# Why is the array not printing the very first element?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to implement a class that behaves similar to an array of strings in C++. Here's the code of the class:

```
class DynamicStringArray{
public:
    DynamicStringArray()
    :dynamicArray(nullptr), size(0){}
    int get_size(){return size;}
    void addEntry(const string& s);
    string operator[](const int &i){return dynamicArray[i];}
private:
    int size;
    string* dynamicArray;
};
```

And here's the code of `addEntry(const string& s)` :

```
void DynamicStringArray::addEntry(const string& s){
    string* tempArr = new string[size + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){ tempArr[i] = dynamicArray[i];}
    tempArr[size] = s;
    size += 1;
    dynamicArray = tempArr;
    delete[] tempArr;
}
```

If I want to print a string in the "array" I would use the [] operator as per my overloaded function. **But my problem is that the first element is not being printed. Why is that happening?**
Here's my `int main()`:

```
DynamicStringArray arr;
arr.addEntry("hello");
arr.addEntry("hey");
cout << arr[0] << endl; // doesn't print anything
cout << arr[1] << endl; // prints hey
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of `addEntry`, you assign `tempArr` to `dynamicArray`, and **then delete it**. This means you're reading from freed memory, which will result in undefined behavior. Instead of deleting `tempArr`, you should delete the old `dynamicArray` you no longer need:

```cpp
void DynamicStringArray::addEntry(const string& s){
    string* tempArr = new string[size + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){ tempArr[i] = dynamicArray[i];}
    tempArr[size] = s;
    size += 1;
    delete[] dynamicArray; // Here!
    dynamicArray = tempArr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

These two lines are a major problem that will lead to *undefined behavior* down the line:

```
dynamicArray = tempArr;
delete[] tempArr;
```

After the first line, the assignment to `dynamicArray` you have two pointer (`dynamicArray` and `tempArr`) pointing *to the very same memory!*

By doing `delete[] tempArr` you invalidate the `dynamicArray` pointer.

What you probably should be doing is to first delete the *old* memory allocated for `dynamicArray` and then just do the assignment:

```
delete[] dynamicArray;
dynamicArray = tempArr;
```